# take and save picture with specified size (in KB-s)

Tags: android

in my app I take a picture and save it in specified way. My phone is Nexus 4 and the camera is very strong and every picture is about 2.31MB how can I save picture for example in 60KB? 
Can I do it with code? and how?

```
File newdir = new File(dir);
         if(!newdir.exists()){
             newdir.mkdirs();
         }
        picturesCount++;
        String file = dir+picturesCount+".jpg";
        imagePath = file;
        File newfile = new File(file);
        try {
            newfile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {}       
        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newfile);
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
```

Comment: I don't think you will get the size of image until you save it somewhere, all you can do is reduce the quality and you will get notable difference

Comment: And how to reduce its quality?

Comment: Do you have some code you done so far?

Comment: I have added the code part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using camera and picture is taken, you can perform the task in the method below to reduce the quality of the image and type like JPEG or PNG `(PNG takes more space than JPEG`) so just play with the value `(60 current out of 100)` and see the difference in size.

```
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    Bitmap preview_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    preview_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

    FileOutputStream outStream = null;
    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Image1.jpg"));
        outStream.write(byteArray);
        outStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("CAMERA", e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("CAMERA", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```